# Запись данных в файл и чтение с помощью thread

Tags: java

Я пишу бота и у меня возник вопрос: нужно ли создавать отдельный поток для чтения/записи данных, чтобы не мешать другим процессам в боте?

Если нужно, то можете привести в качестве примера запись строки "hello world" в файл "foo.txt"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get("foo.txt"), "Hello World".getBytes());
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Нужно ли создавать отдельный поток, чтобы не мешать главному, или можно не волноваться на этот счет?

Comment: Это зависит от того, как устроен бот, какие объёмы ввода/вывода и как часто происходит ввод/вывод.

Comment: Объемы маленькие. запись данных происходит раз в 1-2 минуты

Comment: + Паралельно происходит пару процессов

Comment: Тогда стоит попробовать сначала поработать без дополнительных потоков.

Comment: Понял) Но все равно спасибо за ответ!